# Trouble converting code from VBA to Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

*I am having issues converting this code from VBA to python, it's a function that needs to be converted to python instead of VBA*

```
Function NC(SPL, pond) As Single

    Dim A As Single
    Dim B As Single
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim SPL1(8) As Single
    B = 0
    
    If pond = "A" Then
        SPL1(1) = SPL(1) + 26.2228
        SPL1(2) = SPL(2) + 16.1897
        SPL1(3) = SPL(3) + 8.6748
        SPL1(4) = SPL(4) + 3.2478
        SPL1(5) = SPL(5)
        SPL1(6) = SPL(6) - 1.2017
        SPL1(7) = SPL(7) - 0.9636
        SPL1(8) = SPL(8) + 1.1469
    Else
        SPL1(1) = SPL(1)
        SPL1(2) = SPL(2)
        SPL1(3) = SPL(3)
        SPL1(4) = SPL(4)
        SPL1(5) = SPL(5)
        SPL1(6) = SPL(6)
        SPL1(7) = SPL(7)
        SPL1(8) = SPL(8)
    End If
    
    For I = 1 To 8
        If I = 1 Then
            A = 1.5215 * SPL1(1) - 57.029
        ElseIf I = 2 Then
            A = 1.2855 * SPL1(2) - 31.628
        ElseIf I = 3 Then
            A = 1.1853 * SPL1(3) - 18.938
        ElseIf I = 4 Then
            A = 1.0888 * SPL1(4) - 8.5807
        ElseIf I = 5 Then
            A = 1.019 * SPL1(5) - 2.0793
        ElseIf I = 6 Then
            A = 0.9922 * SPL1(6) + 1.2421
        ElseIf I = 7 Then
            A = 0.9738 * SPL1(7) + 3.2226
        ElseIf I = 8 Then
            A = 0.9738 * SPL1(8) + 4.1964
        End If
        If A > B Then
            B = A
        End If
    Next I
    
    NC = Int(Round(B + 0.5))
    
End Function
```

**This is what I have so far in python but it is giving me an error[code error in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzXKE.png)** the error says it's an indexing issue in python I would like to solve that error so that the function works but not  sure how exactly to solve it

```
    def NC(SPL,pond):
        SPL1 =[(0.0 for x in range(0,8))]
        B = 0.0
        if pond == 'A':
            SPL1[0] = SPL[0] + 26.228
            SPL1[1] = SPL[1] + 16.1897
            SPL1[2] = SPL[2] + 8.6748
            SPL1[3] = SPL[3] + 3.2478
            SPL1[4] = SPL[4]
            SPL1[5] = SPL[5] - 1.2017
            SPL1[6] = SPL[6] - 0.9636
            SPL1[7] = SPL[7] + 1.1469
        else:
            SPL1[0] = SPL[0]
            SPL1[1] = SPL[1] 
            SPL1[2] = SPL[2] 
            SPL1[3] = SPL[3] 
            SPL1[4] = SPL[4]
            SPL1[5] = SPL[5] 
            SPL1[6] = SPL[6] 
            SPL1[7] = SPL[7] 
        for i in range(0, 8):
            if i == 0:
                A = 1.5215 * SPL1[0] -57.029
            if i == 1:
                A = 1.2855 * SPL1[1] -31.628
            if i == 2:
                A = 1.1853 * SPL1[2] -18.938   
            if i == 3:
                A = 1.0888 * SPL1[3] -8.5807     
            if i == 4:
                A = 1.019 * SPL1[4] -2.0793
            if i == 5:
                A = 0.9922 * SPL1[5] +1.2421
            if i == 6:
                A = 0.9738 * SPL1[6] +3.2226
            if i == 7:
                A = 0.9738 * SPL1[7] +4.1964    
            if A > B:
                B = A
        return int(B+0.5)
```

Comment: what have you tried? You can create an integer variable in python is just doing `I = 0` then you just need to add conditionals and a for loop. Looks quite straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamically typed and 0 base indexed. Also by convention lower-case variable names are used. So your code would be something along the lines of:

```
def nc(spl, pond):
    
    spl1 =[0.0 for _ in range(8))]
    
    b = 0.0
    
    if pond == 'A':
        spl1[0] = spl[0] + 26.228
        #and so on
    else:
        spl1[0] = spl[0]
        # and so on

    for i in range(0, 8):
        if i == 0:
            a = 1.5215 * spl1[0] -57.029
            # and so on
        if a > b:
            b = a
    
    return int(b+0.5)
```